# Connot find declaration to go to

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes, navigationview

**SOLVED, *below codes are ok, An external library was causing this problem.***

I have a `NavigationView` with a custom theme in my `style`:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_state_list"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
android:theme="@style/navTheMe"

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**Style (navTheMe)** :

```
<style name="navTheMe" parent="AppThemee">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">90dip</item>
</style>
```

But it cannot find my theme and it says:

> cannot find declaration to go to

And my theme will not be applied

It has been hours and I cannot figure it out what is going on

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the second **e** from the *parent* attribute in *style.xml*

```
<style name="navTheMe" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">90dip</item>
</style>
```

And also, to apply this new theme to your **NavigationView** layout, you should use **app:theme=""@style/navTheMe"** attribute instead of **android:theme="@style/navTheMe**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    ...
    app:theme="@style/navTheMe">
        ...
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,`Appthemee` is my theme name.. I've  changed `android` prefix to `app`, it is finding my theme now but still, it is not applying it

Comment: Can you post the **Appthemee** theme? Thank you

Comment: I just found the problem, recently I've added a library in my project, I just realized, that library was causing this problem, I don't know why exactly, So I removed it from my project and now I'm using another library with the same function, I appreciate your help BTW